# windows phone peer-to-peer - emulator don't see second emulator

Tags: sockets, emulation, windows-phone-7

Based on this article: http://blog.functionalfun.net/2011/02/how-to-deploy-to-and-debug-multiple.html I started example game on 2 emulators  (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickyt/archive/2011/06/15/windows-phone-peer-to-peer-multiplayer-game-using-sockets-in-xna.aspx)

but they cannot see each other...

exception:
[System.Net.Sockets.SocketException]    {"An unknown, invalid, or unsupported option or level was specified in a getsockopt or setsockopt call"}    System.Net.Sockets.SocketException

Comment: Are you using the example from the second article? Or do you have code of your own, because if so, post it here!

Comment: I checked Platformer example modified by Ricky Tan, and Silverlight game rockPaperScissor available from msdn so i assume the problem isn't in the code..

Comment: msdn example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286407%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

Comment: ok, same example working on my  friend machine. Other examples from WP7.1 working on my machine, i've turned off  firewall with no progress..

Comment: I've tried sample: http://www.pitorque.de/MisterGoodcat/post/Windows-Phone-7-Mango-Sockets.aspx  and that one is working, but this one working with server so it's not solve my problem, but maybe useful information

Answer (score 1):

There is only very limited socket support in the emulator. *-Sorry. just looked but can't find the link :(*

If you want to use sockets you'll have to test with an actual device(s).

Comment: Double negative. My IRC client works just fine in the emulator.

Answer (score -1):

Windows phone and thus silverlight doesn't support "listen" command and they can only act as an client so you can't create peer to peer application in this platform.